# How to test controller created via module.config in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller defined in following manner, it works perfect. But when I try to test this controller it says the "(controller name)" is not a function, got undefined". How can I test the controller defined this way.

controller.js

```
var mainModule = angular.module('module1');

function home($scope) {
    $scope.test = "hello";
}
home.$inject = ["$scope"];

mainModule.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: home
        });
    }
]);
```

testSpec.js

```
describe("Test home controller", function () {
  beforeEach(module('module1'));
    it("test the controller ", inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        var ctrl = $controller("home", {
            $scope: $rootScope
        });
        expect($rootScope.items.length).toBe(3);
    }));
});
```

Comment: You can probably use [`$injector.instantiate`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) to create a new instance of your `home` controller. But is there any reason why you are creating controllers in the global scope? This is clearly discouraged in the [official documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) (check the first note).

Comment: No its not in global scope, I have many modules , its like per module basis. Can you elaborate or point me as to how can I use $injector.instantiate

Comment: In the code you posted `home` is declared in the global scope. Your code should already work, because the [`$controller`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller) service checks for `window[constructor]` on the global window object. But apparently `window['home']` is `undefined`.

Comment: Ok now I get what you meant. I couldn't find a reference how to inject controller by $injector.insatantiate any help on that is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by @PaoloMoretti, you shouldn't define your controller in global scope (unless prototyping).  Instead definie the controller as part of the module:

```
var mainModule = angular.module('module1');

mainModule.controller('home', function($scope) {

    $scope.test = "hello";
});
```

Then, when you use this line in the test:

```
beforeEach(module('module1'));
```

The controller will be available for testing.